# cross_val_score default scoring not consistent?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, decision-tree

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html),

for the `cross_val_score`'s `scoring` parameter:
**If None, the estimator’s default scorer (if available) is used.**

For a `DecisionTreeRegressor`, the default criterion is `mse`. So why am I getting different results here?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)


dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=0.26)

- cross_val_score(dt, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

>>> array([ 46.94808341,  18.78121305,  18.19914701,  18.06935431,
        17.19546733,  28.91247609,  39.41410887,  21.30453162,
        31.96443414,  23.74191199])


cross_val_score(dt, X_train, y_train, cv=10)

>>> array([ 0.35723619,  0.75254466,  0.7181376 ,  0.65718608,  0.72531937,
        0.4752839 ,  0.43169728,  0.63916363,  0.41406146,  0.68977882])
```

If I had to guess, it seems the default `scoring` is `R2` instead of `mse`. Is my understanding of default scorer correct or is this a bug?

Comment: I would like to help you if you tell me the dataset you are working on

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG

target variable is `mpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default scorer of a `DecisionTreeRegression` is the `r2-score`, you can find it in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) of the DecisionTreeRegression.

```
 score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]

    Return the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

    The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total sum of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0.
```

Answer (score 2):

@PV8 is definitely right, but I want to point out two details.

Detail #1: How to use `r2-score` as a scoring metric? The answer: `make_scorer`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=0.26)
print(cross_val_score(dt, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring=make_scorer(r2_score)))
```

If you run this program multiple times you will still get different results.

Detail #2: How to get consistent results?

You need to set `random_state` variable to get a constant results.

For instance:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=0.26)
print(cross_val_score(dt, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring=make_scorer(r2_score)))
```

The result is always the same.